# Is there a better way to design this message passing code?

Tags: c++

class A was using below two functions to build and send messages 1 & 2

```
builder::prepareAndDeliverMsg1(msg1_arg1,msg1_arg2)
{
}

builder::prepareAndDeliverMsg2(msg2_arg1,msg2_arg2)
{
}
```

Now, a new class B is introduced, which would like to do what A was doing  in two stages

stage1->prepare
stage2->deliver

I was thinking to extend the builder class like below:

```
///----

builder::prepareMsg1(msg1_arg1,msg1_arg2)
{
}

builder::prepareMsg2(msg2_arg1,msg2_arg2)
{
}

builder::deliverMsg1(msg1_arg1)
{
    This function, inserts re-calculated msg1_arg1 into the prepared message in stage1
}

builder::deliverMsg2(msg2_arg1)
{
   This function, inserts re-calculated msg2_arg1 into the prepared message in stage1
}

// These two functions are still retained for the usage of class A
builder::prepareAndDeliverMsg1(msg1_arg1,msg1_arg2)
{
}

builder::prepareAndDeliverMsg2(msg2_arg1,msg2_arg2)
{
}

//---
```

I would like to know, if there is any better way of designing this ?

Comment: Thanks for all the gurus who answered here...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Darks idea you can have a base class that implements the combined prepare and delivers in terms of the separate functions and allows deriving classes to override those as required:

```
class base {
    virtual bool prepareMsg1() = 0;
    virtual bool prepareMsg2() = 0;
    virtual bool deliverMsg1() = 0;
    virtual bool deliverMsg2() = 0;
    bool prepareAndDeliverMsg1(){
        prepareMsg1();
        deliverMsg1();
    }
    bool prepareAndDeliverMsg2(msg2_arg1,msg2_arg2){
        prepareMsg2();
        deliverMsg2();
    }
};
```

You may find that a lot of the functionality from the two derived classes is the same in which case you won't want to use pure virtuals in the base class:

```
class base {
    virtual bool prepareMsg1(args) {//not pure virtual
        //do the common stuff
    }
};

class derived {
    bool prepareMsg1( args ) {
        base::prepareMsg1(args);
        //code to specailise the message
    }
};
```

It could even be that the base class implments your original class but allows your second class to be derived without having to repeat the common code.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, though your solution requires a re-write of the existing code.I would like to do it for more neater solution. The fellow who had written the existing C++ codem , used more C than C++....

Comment: Remember to always define a virtual destructor in a class that has (or derives from a class that has) at least one virtual function.  Or else you may be surprised to see that your derived class's destructor is not called in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

maybe for each message, create your own class and inherit from the base message class?

```
class TBaseMsg
{
public:
   virtual void prepare() = 0;
   virtual void deliver() = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Decorator design pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks ok to me.